# How can I unit test that an Exception is NOT raised when certain conditions are met?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing the following unit test:

```
if not mock_finfo['ready'] and parser_extra_params['force']:
    with pytest.raises(ValueError,
                       match=f'Missing input files for pass1 '
                       f'for {parser_code}|{data_file_group} on {dte}.'):
        pass1(parser_code, data_file_group, dte)
```

But rather than testing if the `ValueError` is raised under certain circumstances (i.e. when `not mock_finfo['ready']` and `parser_extra_params['force']`), I want to test that NO EXCEPTION is raised under these conditions- is there a way to do this?

I have read some other articles, but I couldn't quite adjust my above code to do what I want it to.

Comment: Just remove `with pytest.raises(...):` - if the call to `pass1` errors, the test will fail. But I wouldn't recommend having conditional logic in your test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks for the answer- in my case this is part of a bigger code so sadly i need conditional logic, but I understand this is not good practice. Could you suggest what you mean by removing `with pytest.raises(...):` ? Does everything else stay the same?

Comment: So is it literally just the first and last line?

Comment: `with pytest.raises(...):` catches the expected error. If you *don't* expect an error, you don't need it (indeed it's suppressing an error you don't want, which is actively unhelpful).

Comment: But wouldn't I need to have some `assert` statement to show the reader what I am testing? - rather than just running the function with certain inputs, and this causing an error?

Comment: You've told us nothing about what this function does _apart_ from that it shouldn't throw an error, so: probably, yes, but we've no idea what it would be.